# How do I make my NSNotification trigger a selector?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, nsnotifications, nsnotification

Here's the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSURL *musicURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://live-three2.dmd2.ch/buureradio/buureradio.m3u"];

    if([musicURL scheme])
    {
        MPMoviePlayerController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:musicURL];
        if (mp)
        {
            // save the music player object
            self.musicPlayer = mp;
            [mp release];

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popBack:) name:@"MPMoviePlayerDidExitFullscreenNotification" object:nil];

            // Play the music!
            [self.musicPlayer play];
        }
    }   
}

-(void)popBack:(NSNotification *)note
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

The selector method never gets called.  I just want to pop back to the root menu when the "Done" button is pressed on the movie player.  I put an NSLog in the selector to check if it was even being called, nothing.  The music plays fine.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(popBack:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:nil];
```